# Which is the best software for making games

Tags: android

I want to make game of arms and ammunition in the big world.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! [What's "best" is always subjective](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/157/185): *one man's trash is another man's treasure.* Better describe what would make this software *fitting best for you* – which then enables us to give fitting recommendations. See [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for more hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many choices of softwares but I will list most popular of them. Also its called `engine`. `engine` is where you develop games, like `Fortnite` and `PUBG Mobile` is developed on `Unreal Engine` engine. Anyway, here is list of most popular softwares to develop games:

1. Wrike
2. Visual Studio
3. Blender
4. Unity
5. Unreal Engine
6. GameMaker: Studio
7. Helix Core

and many more...

[Here is list of best game engines](https://www.capterra.com/game-development-software/) and
[this is 'full' list of game engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines.)

Also remember to ask good questions. Here is link to help: [How to ask good question?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)